# Fuzzy Merge 2 Data Frames on Time in r

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames that I need to merge. The fields I want to merge on are IP address and time (%H:%M). I'm looking for exact match in the IP address field, but in the time field I want a fuzzy match within 5 minutes (+/-). For example, if I had the following 2 dataframes:

```
> df1
  users1 IPs1        times1
1  user1 192.168.1.1  11:05
2  user2 192.168.1.2  20:31
3  user3 192.168.1.3  01:19

> df2
  users2 IPs2         times2
1  userx 192.168.1.2  20:33
2  usery 192.168.1.3  01:19
3  userz 192.168.1.1  11:01
```

And I wanted to merge the dataframes to show that user1 correlates with userz, user2 correlates with userx, and user3 correlates with usery. How could I do that? With the merge function I would only get user3 correlates with usery based on exact time matches.

Comment: Can you please add expected output to your question?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` for easily reproducible data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fuzzyjoin` package to merge fuzzily. One of the `fuzzyjoin` functions is `difference_join` which allows you to join based on the absolute difference between columns in two tables. The only problem is, `times1` and `times2` are factors or character vectors, not numerical. So I used `hms` to turn them into numerical columns, and then left joined fuzzily on a 5-minute (5*60 seconds) difference, and filtered for when IPs are identical to each other.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(hms)

hms <- Vectorize(hms)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  separate(times1, c("hours", "minutes")) %>%
  mutate_at(c("hours", "minutes"), as.integer) %>%
  mutate(times = hms(0, minutes, hours))

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  separate(times2, c("hours", "minutes")) %>%
  mutate_at(c("hours", "minutes"), as.integer) %>%
  mutate(times = hms(0, minutes, hours))


difference_full_join(df1, df2, by = "times", max_dist = 5*60) %>%
  filter(IPs1 == IPs2)
#>   users1        IPs1 hours.x minutes.x times.x users2        IPs2 hours.y
#> 1  user1 192.168.1.1      11         5   39900  userz 192.168.1.1      11
#> 2  user2 192.168.1.2      20        31   73860  userx 192.168.1.2      20
#> 3  user3 192.168.1.3       1        19    4740  usery 192.168.1.3       1
#>   minutes.y times.y
#> 1         1   39660
#> 2        33   73980
#> 3        19    4740
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it took me so long to get back to you, but life happened this week. This worked perfectly (after I figured out that I had imported my data strings as factors). I appreciate the help and this really motivates me to continue to learn more r.